# Hashicorp Vault List PKI Endpoints: How can I list all the defined Paths for a PKI/Secrets engine within Vault?

Tags: apache-kafka, hashicorp-vault

I used Canonical's Juju Vault Charm to deploy Hashicorp Vault and uploaded an intermediate certificate "vault inter cert" for internal communication Kafka/Zookeeper (PKI based communication). The internal communications between Kafka Brokers and Zookeeper clients using Vault CA works fine, however, I would like my K8s applications (ingress) to use this Vault PKI to acquire leaf certificates that would allow them to talk to internal services such as Kafka/Zookeeper and consume topics etc.

In order to enable it, I am using AppRole within Vault and create an Ingress rule where I have to define the Vault Path.

I am not sure what this path should be?

How can I list all the defined Paths/Endpoints for a PKI/Secrets engine within Vault?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best place to see all the endpoints is to check the tool i.e. Vault API - that will defined all the endpoints. Eg: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/auth/approle

Don't think there is a "query" that will list all the endpoints.